# NSInternalInconsistencyException when i use UISplitViewController and UITabViewController

Tags: ios

I want to build this structure just like  the flows:[image]

But when i was running this demo, there was a exception:

```
2015-07-22 21:54:41.697 Test[3884:2992098] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/zhanggui/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DEBA893C-5DF5-4A9A-AAAD-D992CAED1185/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/DA15E304-CD75-4739-9AF9-2B930CA84EFF/Test.app> (loaded)' with name 'TIt-bJ-Hqi-view-AtR-6S-RDw''
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x02047746 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00531a97 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0204766d +[NSException raise:format:] + 141
    3   UIKit                               0x00ab9ddf -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1003
    4   UIKit                               0x008d40d4 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 270
    5   UIKit                               0x008d486b -[UIViewController loadView] + 295
    6   UIKit                               0x008d4a9f -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 78
    7   UIKit                               0x008d5045 -[UIViewController view] + 35
    8   UIKit                               0x00924cdf -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:transition:shouldSetSelected:] + 426
    9   UIKit                               0x0092431f -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:] + 64
    10  UIKit                               0x009204db -[UITabBarController _setSelectedViewController:] + 339
    11  UIKit                               0x00920295 -[UITabBarController setSelectedIndex:] + 115
    12  UIKit                               0x0091fe41 __51-
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear as if the problem is in the layout of the views, but in how the views are being presented. This is because of the line "Could not load NIB in bundle:". It is most likely the nib is misspelled, you're loading it from the wrong bundle, or it's not a NIB file you mean to be loading at all.